# Does FastMM support reserving virtual memory and calling in chunks to grow an array?

Tags: delphi, virtual-memory, fastmm

I know I can reserve virtual memory using VirtualAlloc.
e.g. I can claim 1GB of virtual memory and then call in the first MB of that to put my a growing array into.
When the array grows beyond 1MB I call in the 2nd MB and so on.
This way I don't need to move the array around in memory when it grows, it just stays in place and the Intel/AMD virtual memory manager takes care of my problems.

However does FastMM support this structure, so I don't have to do my own memory management?

Pseudo code:

```
type
  PBigarray = ^TBigarray;
  TBigArray = array[0..0] of SomeRecord;

....

begin
  VirtualMem:= FastMM.ReserveVirtualMemory(1GB);
  PBigArray:= FastMM.ClaimPhysicalMemory(VirtualMem, 1MB);
....

procedure GrowBigArray
begin
  FastMM.ClaimMorePhysicalMemory(PBigArray, 1MB {extra});
  //will generate OOM exception when claim exceeds 1GB
```

Does FastMM support this?

Comment: This has the hallmarks of being an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm guessing as to what your real problems are, but I suspect you are suffering from address space fragmentation because your code requires large contiguous blocks of memory. If so then the best solution is to allocate non-contiguous blocks and then *piece them together* behind the scenes so that these smaller blocks look like a contiguous block.

Comment: What you're asking is highly specialized behavior that's easily handled with `VirtualAlloc`; Why would a general-purpose memory manager do that?

Comment: @David, thanks for looking out for me. I don't have memory fragmentation yet, because I have not written the program yet :-). I know I have a program that's going to use all available memory, so I'm researching my options. This will not turn out into a long Q&A, simple yes/no will do, and I guess it's a no.

Comment: @Johan Yeah, I think no is the answer. I can help you with the address space fragmentation issue when you do get round to writing the program. I trust you are well aware of IMAGE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE.

Comment: @David, I didn't know it was called that, but I knew you can ask Windows to give you more virtual memory.

Comment: A very common misconception is that committing (VirtualAlloc with MEM_COMMIT) uses any physical memory. It. Does. Not. All it does is increase the "total committed memory" counter of the OS, and if that is now larger than total physical memory + total swap file size, the OS will start increasing the swap file in the expectation it might need it later. But there is no physical memory of any kind associated with this allocation yet. Only when the memory in question is actually being accessed will the OS assign empty pages from the zeroed pages pool on a page by page basis as needed.

Comment: @Johan, please note that using AWE means that the OS has less memory available and that may mean it slows down. Not an issue so much if you have a dedicated machine, but can be significant on machines running multiple services/apps simultaneously.

Comment: @Marjan Venema, I don't think Johan was talking about AWE, with "ask windows to give you more virtual memory" he was probably refering to the /3GB switch under 32-bit windows, or simply running a Win32 app under 64-bit windows (which gives full 4 GB, in both cases assuming that IMAGE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE is used)

Comment: @Thorsten: sorry I keep getting my abbreviations wrong in this area. I did mean that pesky /3GB switch as it (on Win32) leaves the OS with only 1GB instead of 2GB to do its own bidding.

Comment: @Marjan Venema, ah, ok. Then I fully agree, the /3GB switch does in many cases more harm than good. But it's pretty much irrelevant today. Which newer system is running the 32bit version of windows now a days? And when running (as Win32 program) under a 64bit version of windows, you not just 3GB, but full 4GB address space, without disadvantages, by using the IMAGE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, FastMM4 (as of the latest version I looked at) does not explicitly support this. It's really not a functionality you would expect in a general purpose memory manager as it's trivially simple to do with VirtualAlloc calls.

NexusMM4 (which is part of NexusDB) does something that gives you a similar result, but without wasting all the address space before it is needed in the background.

If you make an initial large allocation (directly via GetMem, or indirectly via a dynamic array or such) the memory is allocated in just the size needed, via VirtualAlloc.

But if that allocation is then resized to a larger size, NexusMM will use a different way to allocate memory which allows it to simply unmap the allocation from the address space an remap it again, at a larger size, when further reallocs takes place.

This prevents the 2 major problems that most general purpose memory managers have when reallocating:

- during a normal realloc the existing and new allocation need to be present in the address space at the same time, temporarily doubling the address space and physical memory requirements
- during a normal realloc, the whole contents of the existing allocation needs to be copied

So with NexusMM you would get all the advantages of what you showed in your pseudo code (with the exception that the first realloc will involve a copy, and that growing your array might change it's address) by simply using normal GetMem/ReallocMem/FreeMem calls.